# Intervention to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

My institution which I'm responsible to obey their writing rules for my PhD dissertation does not have any LaTeX templates and they insist on their weird MS Word template. They do not accept the text I've written with LaTeX. Even though i have tried to imitate the Word template which they provided and i have achieved desired properties in  most of the text a fair amount of issue still remains. One big issue for me is; they want me to put a specific little title on the page number column of table of contents. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

[image]